# TYPO3 Extbase query based on other table

Tags: sql, typo3, extbase

I got to table where one related to the other

```
TABLE A
uid
name

TABLE B
uid
name
rel_table_a
```

Now I would like:

```
// find all table A that is related to by table B
public function findAllTableAThatIsRelatedToByTableB() {
  $query = $this->createQuery();

  // what should this line be?
  //$query->matching($query->count(tableB.rel_table_a = uid));

    return $query->execute();
}
```

Is that possible or will the relation need to be created in the TCA for Table A first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use related tables in the queries, but first you need to set up your `TCA` and your models properly, otherwise extbase does not know how your tables are related.

As the query condition you could just check if the relation exists.

In your structure we can only do this query on the table B since your table A does not have a relation field, so in this example you will get all items from table B that have a table A element related.

```
$query->matching($query->greaterThan('rel_table_a.uid', 0));
```

If you have an 1:n relation from table A to table B, then you should use an inline field. This way you can do a query on the table A: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Inline/Index.html

PS: you can not use `$query->count` inside a `$query->matching`

Comment: Hi Dimitri. Thanks a lot. I will try to add the relation on TableA as well to be able to make the query